# What are the various uses of あまり?

Tags: grammar, usage

I'm a beginner and I would like to know how あまり is used.

Comment: Here are some free resources online with example sentences of various quality: [ALC](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E3%81%82%E3%81%BE%E3%82%8A&ref=sa) - [Progressive J-E](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/detail?p=%E3%81%82%E3%81%BE%E3%82%8A&stype=0&dtype=3) - [Tanaka Corpus](http://jisho.org/sentences?jap=%E3%81%82%E3%81%BE%E3%82%8A&eng=)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This won't be all the uses of あまり but it should give you some idea how it is used :)

**As a noun:**
It can be used simply as a noun meaning "the rest"; "the remainder".

> 給料の余りで本を買った
>   He bought books with *what was left* of his pay.
>   食事の余りは捨てた
>   The *remains* of the meal were thrown away.

It can also be used as a grammar point `～（の）あまり（に）～` showing the result of having too strong an emotion. It connects to nouns with `の` or just comes straight after verbs.

> あの時はショックのあまり何もできなかったんです。
>   I was *too* shocked to do anything at that time.
>   うれしさのあまり彼女は踊りだした
>   She was *so* happy that she danced for joy.
>   将来を心配するあまり現在のことがおろそかになる
>   worry *so much* about the future that you neglect the present

**As a na-adjective:**
Expresses that something is extreme; too much; beyond expectations

> あまりに多くの間違いをする
>   make *too* many mistakes
>   あまりにきれいで食べるのがもったいないように見える
>   look *too* good to eat

**As an adverb:**
Comes before the verb as an adverb expressing that somebody is doing something too much, more than they should.

> あまり勉強するとからだを壊すよ
>   If you study *too much* you'll ruin your health

With a negative, expresses "not very much". This usage in particular is very common and often becomes `あんまり` or `あんま` in casual speech.

> あまりよくない
>   *Not very* good
>   あまり可愛くない
>   *Not so* cute
>   あまり食べない
>   Don't eat *very much*

**As a suffix:**
Comes after a counter to express that something is more than the amount

> 百名余りの従業員
>   *More than* 100 employees
>   5年余り前に
>   *More than* five years ago

Example sentences and information from:

- [goo辞書 (goo Dictionary)](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/)
- [英辞郎 (Eijirou)](https://eow.alc.co.jp/)

Comment: For the '（の）あまり（に）' grammar, you can think of it in English as 'A so much so that B'