# あんまり versus あまり

Tags: word-choice

What is the difference between あんまり and あまり? Please also provide me with some examples.

Comment: This really seems to delve down to personal preference in my experience, however the more accepted way to say it is あまり

Comment: Will [this post](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/12377/what-are-the-various-uses-of-%E3%81%82%E3%81%BE%E3%82%8A/12378#12378) be of some help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They can be used interchangeably, but あんまり sounds a bit more colloquial than あまり.

Examples:

あまり関{かん}心{しん}がありません = "I'm not particularly interested"

あんまり興{きょう}味{み}がないね = "I'm not particularly interested"

*** Added ***

I can think of only one situation where あんまり is appropriate and あまり is not, namely

それは、あんまりだ = That's too much / too hideous / too ridiculous etc.

We don't say それは、あまりだ

Comment: That last one does seem to be more dialect driven. I have heard それは、あまりやな～ before. However it could have been that the dialect toned down the ん sound enough that it was difficult to notice.

Comment: < それは、あまりやな～> That's plausible, but I can't (dis)confirm, as I do not live in Kansai area. Probably @Choko can share her wisdom here.

Comment: 関西でも、「That's too much.」「それは、ひどい。」という意味で、「それは、あまりやな～」ということはありません。やはり、「あんまり」を使います。「[そら]{HH}、[あんまりやな]{HHHHLH}。」と聞くと、「それはひどい。」または、「それは、いまいちだ。」のどちらかの意味かな、と思います。

Comment: だったら、「ん」が聞きにくかったかな？